# ms access query update concat

Tags: ms-access

Hello I need to do something like this:

```
"UPDATE tbl SET pozn=CONCAT(pozn, '"+attach_str+"') WHERE id=1"
```

what am I doing wrong? it seems CONCAT is not working. I need to attach string to original data in pozn field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use &

```
UPDATE tbl SET pozn= pozn & "some string" WHERE id=1
```

Or for VBA

```
s="UPDATE tbl SET pozn= pozn & '" & attach_str & "' WHERE id=1"
```